# Update several properties of an array of objects in React (onClick={ change celsius to fahrenheit on setState})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Update:**
I have modified my question and change my example code to make it as simple and self explanatory as possible.

From the openweathermap API I'm getting an **array of objects**...something very similar to this:

```
    // Returned JSON already parsed ( I used "Axios" for the GET request)
    const obj = [
      {name: "Hong-Kong", main: {temp: 34, humidity: 33}}, 
      {{name: "Ontario", main: {temp: 14, humidity: 3}}, 
      {{name: "Poland", main: {temp: 54, humidity: 9}}
    ]
```

My **App** Component looks something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: obj
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <Card weatherData={this.state.data}/>
       </div>

    )
  }
}
```

In my **Card** Component I am using **.map** to render 3 beautiful cards with all the weather info that Im passing from the state of the App Component as a prop (weatherData) to my Card Component:

```
function Class(props) {
  const convertToFahrenheit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Grab every single celsius and do the math to fahrenheit
    // I would need some sort of dynamic variable on the {d.main.temp}
  }


    {props.weatherData.map(d => {
       return (
         <div>
           <p>{d.name}</p>
           <p>{d.main.temp}</p>
           <p>{d.main.humidity}</p>
           <button onClick={convertToFahrenheit}>to_fahrenheit</button>
           <button>to_celsius</button>
         </div>
       )
    })}
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to change the celsius to Fahrenheit on the Card Component when I click on the Fahrenheit button, and viceversa.

I don't know if I should manage this on the App Component and try to update the temperature on the state or find a clever way to do it in the Class functional Component. I am lost.

Please advice, help, I've been stuck on this already for a week...should I use Inmutable and Redux for this situation?

Comment: where are you usinh toCelcius method in App.js ?

Comment: Hi @SakhiMansoor thanks for taking a look. I am going to use it but I want to make it work first with toFahrenheit, no worries about that.

Comment: Uncomment the line that says `// console.log(celsiusData);` What does it log out? I expect you'll see that it's an array with exactly one element. That element happens to be an array of integers. So you've accidentally created a 2 dimensional array, when really you just want that inner array on its own.

Comment: Hi @NicholasTower, thanks for taking a look to my code. the line `console.log(celsiusData)` is an array of all the celsius integers that Im saving in the state of my App.js Component. Now what I want is to update those celsius data back to state ( which is also something else that I don't know how im gonna do ) . What I want is use my toFahrenheit javascript function to import an array of integers, loop and return the fahrenheit in an array to then import that back into state...

Comment: @NicholasTower I have re-formulated my question.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor  I have re-formulated my question.

Answer (score 0):

First stateless component doesn't have methods, your `Card` component should be stateful.

```
class Card extends React.Component{

  convertToFahrenheit = e => {
    // Grab every single celsius and do the math to fahrenheit
    // I would need some sort of dynamic variable on the {d.main.temp}
  }

render() {
  const { weatherData } = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
    weatherData.map(d => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{d.name}</p>
          <p>{d.main.temp}</p>
          <p>{d.main.humidity}</p>
          <button onClick={this.convertToFahrenheit}>to_fahrenheit</button>
          <button>to_celsius</button>
        </div>
      )
    })
    </div>
  )
}
}
```